# Ubuntu, изменение языка даты и времени

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Всем привет! Ребята, подскажите пожалуйста - поставил свеженькую Ubuntu 16.04, осваиваюсь после винды) Ставил версию на английском, тем не менее дата и время по какой то причине отражена на локальном языке местонахождения - а именно на украинском. Есть какие то варианты изменить на английский?

Comment: 1. какой программой вы получаете «дату и время»? 2. приложите к вопросу вывод программы `locale` (текст, а не картинку, конечно же). изменить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса.

Comment: параметры системы -> язык системы -> региональные форматы?

Comment: просто кликал на время справа вверху)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это возможно.

Открываете `Settings`, выбираете `Language Support`, в окошке нажимаете на таб `Regional formats`. Изменяете язык на  English и нажимаете на кнопку `Apply system wide`.

Чтоб изменения вступили в силу, выйдите из системы, и зайдите снова.

Comment: помогло,
спасибо!